# HTML <button> image with some sort of href

Tags: html

I need to create a button with this image https://www.thebankofmaine.com/images/android-app-on-google-play.png and I need to reference it to a file on my server.

How can I do that ?

I've tried this and the image appears, but dont know how to go to a webpage after clicking.

```
<button type="button" onClick="location.href='index.html'">GO TO URL</button>
```

How can I change it to go to google.com for example and how can I add a img to the button?

Comment: Why don't you just wrap an anchor tag around that image?

Comment: I would do that but I'm not an HTML expert...

Comment: Someone has provided the code for the anchor image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src=" https://www.thebankofmaine.com/images/android-app-on-google-play.png" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to remove the button.You can do this in the a
look the example!

```
<a href="http://web.facebook.com"><img src="include/search.png"></a>
```

Answer (score -1):

I dont exactly get what you are trying to do, but it seems to me that you are just simply trying to make an image a link to click on to lead you somewhere else. This can be done with:

```
<a href="yourlinktogoto">
<img src="yourpicture.gif" alt="Picture Description" style="border:0">
</a>
```

You have to change the src, href, and alt.

You dont have to add the border thing but i put it in almost all my images.

Hopefully it will help. tnx

Comment: Why do you need style="border:0" ?

Comment: border is not supported in html5, but in older browsers i have seen it solve alot of my positioning problems.

Comment: CSS border property is not supported in HTML5 ? Dude, please.

Comment: "The border attribute of <img> is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead."

Comment: Yes, it is about HTML border attribute, not CSS border property. Here, you're using CSS border property, not border HTML attribute.